# 1-click checkout with Bluesnap API

Tags: payment-gateway, bluesnap

When previous customers return to my site, I don’t want them to have to add all their information again. Is there a way to add the customer information automatically and let them do 1-click checkout? I am not storing credit card information in my side, so I need a way to do this with the bluesnap payment API.

Answer (score 0):

BlueSnap supports vaulting shopper information, so to implement 1-click checkout on your site you need to do the following:

When the shopper is creating the first transaction, call the Create Vaulted Shopper API (http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/create-vaulted-shopper)  and store the returned Shopper ID in your system.

Next, you need a way in your UI to identify that the shopper is a returning shopper. You can create a login mechanism on your site (to identify the user) or simply place a cookie on the Shopper’s browser to identify him/her.

When the shopper returns, you call the Retrieve Vaulted Shopper API (http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/retrieve-vaulted-shopper) to retrieve the vaulted information and pass the data to your UI to pre-populate the screen. Note that Bluesnap also stores the billing address, shipping address, phone, email, etc. so you can populate any of that info into your site.